# Hide the new floating language switcher

Tags: windows-10, language

I have recently updated to the new Windows 10 Version 1903 and had an unpleasant encounter with the new floating language switcher when I hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LShift</kbd>.

[image: Floating language switcher location]

The main problem with this floating menu is that it is showing in games and it is really frustrating. Is there any way I could disable the menu but still keep the shortcut for language change?